# Nginx Header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" from multiple domains including 1 js file to anyone

Tags: nginx, syntax, header

Ubuntu 1604 with Nginx 1.14

This code works great for multiple domains with different tlds.

```
   location ~* \.(?:jpg|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
      if ( $http_origin ~* (https?://(.+\.)?(domain|domain|domain)\.(me|systems|com)$) ) {
      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "$http_origin" always;
      }
   }
```

If I change the first location line and add js to allow js files ...

`location ~* \.(?:js|jpg|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {`

It does not work. I only need to add 1 js file that can be used by any website and the path is

`/webbie/build/js/widget.min.js`

1- How can accomplish this?

---

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to allow multiple domains to access with a few tweaks from the OP.

```
   location ~* \.(ttf|ttc|otf|js|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
      if ( $http_origin ~* ((.+\.)?(domain\.systems|domain\.com|domain\.me)) ) {
         add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "$http_origin" always;
      }
   }
```

But I was not able to simply allow 1 js file as of yet. Hopefully, this will help someone else.